# Laravel 4 - Model query not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Understanding models is doing my head in.

Below is my complete model

```
<?php

class Pmconversation extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'pm_conversations';


public function getPrivateMessages()
{

    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    $messages = DB::table('pm_conversations')
                    ->where(function($query) use ($userId) {
                        $query->where('user_one', $userId)
                            ->where('user_one_archived', 0);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($userId) {
                        $query->where('user_two', $userId)
                            ->where('user_two_archived', 0)
                    })->get();

    return $messages;

}

}
```

In my routes.php i have the following:

```
$conversations = Pmconversation::getPrivateMessages();
```

When i load the page im getting

```
syntax error, unexpected '}'
```

its pointing to the })->get(); part of the model ... How can this be possible? ...

I have no idea whats going wrong.

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the missing semi-colon.

```
$messages = DB::table('pm_conversations')
                ->where(function($query) use ($userId) {
                    $query->where('user_one', $userId)
                        ->where('user_one_archived', 0);
                })
                ->orWhere(function($query) use ($userId) {
                    $query->where('user_two', $userId)
                        ->where('user_two_archived', 0);
                })->get();
```

Comment: It's not a case of removing the extra semi-colon, rather adding the one that's missing.

Comment: Ok, now im getting Non-static method Pmconversation::getPrivateMessages() should not be called statically

Comment: @BigJobbies change "public function" to "public static function" and that should fix the static error

Comment: @BigJobbies, so don't call it statically, you are doing OOP so try to avoid static. It's not possible in all the cases but try to avoid it.

Comment: Alrighty ... No more errors yet hahaha ill see how i go ... thanks for that!!